# Adding Mobile Field on Customer create api in Magento2.1.12

Tags: customer-account, mobile, magento2.1.12

I want to add telephone field in customer create API in MAGENTO 2.1.12.Please tell me.

I created customer using api,passing this information:

> { "customer": { "email": "jdoe@example.com", "firstname": "Jane",
>   "lastname": "Doe", "addresses": [{ "defaultShipping": true,
>   "defaultBilling": true, "firstname": "Jane", "lastname": "Doe",
>   "region": { "regionCode": "NY", "region": "New York", "regionId":43 },
>   "postcode": "10755", "street": ["123 Oak Ave"], "city": "Purchase",
>   "telephone": "512-555-1111", "countryId": "US" }] }, "password":
>   "Password1" }

Comment: Please share what you have tried  So far.

Comment: If we create customer without address using rest api V1/customers,then mobile number is not show in Customer ->All Customers.I want to add mobile number on create customers without address.